# Custom ValidationAttribute trigger on different client property change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have built a custom validation attribute - LessThanDifference. Basically I give it two properties, and it checks to see if the value of the validated field is less than the difference of the two property names. Basically "is FieldC < (FieldA - FieldB)". That part works.

The IsValid function works fine, here is my client validation rules. (Bonus question - Is there any way to get the display name for  firstoperand and secondoperand? It has the property name by attribute parameter.)

```
    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
{
    var rule =  new ModelClientValidationRule
    {
        ValidationType = "lessthandifference",
        ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName())
    };

    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("firstoperand", FirstOperand);
    rule.ValidationParameters.Add("secondoperand", SecondOperand);

    yield return rule;

}
```

Where I'm totally lost is how to trigger the validation If A(firstoperand) or B(secondoperand) changes.

```
$.validator.addMethod(
'lessthandifference',
function (value, element, params) {
    var firstVal = $('#' + params.firstoperand).val();
    var secondVal = $('#' + params.secondoperand).val();
    return (value <= (firstVal - secondVal));
});

$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'lessthandifference', ['firstoperand', 'secondoperand'], function (options) {
        var params = {
            firstoperand: options.params.firstoperand,
            secondoperand: options.params.secondoperand
        };
        options.rules['lessthandifference'] = params;
        options.messages['lessthandifference'] = options.message;

    //Set up Trigger?
});
```

I've tried to pass something like (#' + options.params.secondoperand) into another method, but have been unable to get the prop name for the base attribute (FieldC).

$().change seems like it would be the way to go if I could get it set right.

Thoughts?

Comment: I have been struggling with a similar issue, I am trying to get the validation triggered by the change of the dependent property without having to apply the attribute on the dependent property itself.  For example, if you are comparing DateA to DateB and you apply the attribute to DateB and provide DateA as an injected property. I want it to validate the DateB when either DateB or DateA fields are modified by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the main issue:

```
function addSecondaryValidatorCheck(mainElement, secondaryElement) {
    $(secondaryElement).change(function () {
        if ($(mainElement).val() > 0)
            $(mainElement).valid();
    });
```

And Implementation from the $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add function

```
addSecondaryValidatorCheck('#' + options.element.id, '#' + options.params.compareAttribute);
```

Still looking for a good way to pass the display name.